# How do I output results to a .csv file in Python?

Tags: python, csv, text, export-to-csv, data-wrangling

I am new to Python and would like to write a script that that takes a .txt file as input and outputs the results to a .csv file.

The .txt files look as follows

```
text:eub1
region:euboea
μενανδρεσεμεεποισε
```

I would like to write a script that creates a new row for each instance of μ or ν in the third line above. I also want each row to contain the `text` and `region` identifier. So the result should look like this:

```
text,region,letter  
eub1,euboea,μ
eub1,euboea,ν
eub1,euboea,μ
```

I don't really know where to start with the coding, so I'd be grateful for any advice on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {}
with open("your_file.txt", "r") as f_in:
    for line in map(str.strip, f_in):
        if line == "":
            continue
        if line.startswith("text:"):
            data["text"] = line.split(":", maxsplit=1)[-1]
        elif line.startswith("region:"):
            data["region"] = line.split(":", maxsplit=1)[-1]
        else:
            data["letter"] = [ch for ch in line if ch in "μν"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
   text  region letter
0  eub1  euboea      μ
1  eub1  euboea      ν
2  eub1  euboea      ν
3  eub1  euboea      μ
```

and saves `data.csv`:

```
text,region,letter
eub1,euboea,μ
eub1,euboea,ν
eub1,euboea,ν
eub1,euboea,μ
```

---

Content of `your_file.txt`:

```
text:eub1
region:euboea
μενανδρεσεμεεποισε
```

---

EDIT: To load from this file:

```
text:eub1
region:euboea
μενανδρεσεμεεποισε
text:eub2
region:xxx
μμμ
text:eub3
region:zzz
abc
```

you can try:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {}
with open("your_file.txt", "r") as f_in:
    for line in map(str.strip, f_in):
        if line == "":
            continue
        if line.startswith("text:"):
            data.setdefault("text", []).append(line.split(":", maxsplit=1)[-1])
        elif line.startswith("region:"):
            data.setdefault("region", []).append(
                line.split(":", maxsplit=1)[-1]
            )
        else:
            data.setdefault("letter", []).append(
                [ch for ch in line if ch in "μν"]
            )

df = pd.DataFrame(data).explode("letter")
print(df)

df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
   text  region letter
0  eub1  euboea      μ
0  eub1  euboea      ν
0  eub1  euboea      ν
0  eub1  euboea      μ
1  eub2     xxx      μ
1  eub2     xxx      μ
1  eub2     xxx      μ
2  eub3     zzz    NaN
```

and saves `data.csv`:

```
text,region,letter
eub1,euboea,μ
eub1,euboea,ν
eub1,euboea,ν
eub1,euboea,μ
eub2,xxx,μ
eub2,xxx,μ
eub2,xxx,μ
eub3,zzz,
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is fantastic. I just have one follow-up question. If the input .txt file contains more than one set of `text`, `region`, and string of Greek letters, how do I modify the code so that they can all be captured? I can modify the original post to explain this more clearly if that would help.

Comment: I have one more question. How do I amend the code to allow for separate lines of Greek letters (separated by carriage returns) for each `text`?

Comment: @Namenlos I'd recommend to open a new question here on StackOverflow. Put there code you have + problem you're encountering. I'll try to look at it.